# How to use TRUNC for several cells in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, truncate

The thing is there's a column of data with more than 8 decimals, I need each cell to contain 6 decimals max.

Looks like I need to TRUNC every time I need to make it shorter, is there an option to do it for the whole column?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the numbers you want to truncate are in A1:A9. The following formula will deliver what you want:

```
=arrayformula(trunc(A1:A9, 6))
```